# Non-responsive div in layout with image left and text right

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, inline

There's an issue I encounter whenever I go on mobile, the text goes to the far right. I need it to be centered along with the image but what I've tried doesn't work.

I've tried adding `text-align:center;` to the code but the text still doesn't align to the center.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<div class="post-thumb" style="float:left;" ><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551717743-49959800b1f6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0MjB9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" /></div>
    <div class="post-content" style="margin-left:210px;" >
        <h3 class="post-title" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:200%;padding-left:40%;text-align:center;" >Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p style="padding-left:40%">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Note: This is a homework question.

Comment: `padding-left:40%` will occupy 40% of width however the text is aligned center in the remaining 60%;

Comment: removing  style="margin-left:210px;" or style="padding-left:40%" is not an option ?

Comment: This is a homework question so SO guidelines are that we try to help you get there yourself rather than giving you the code. In your design, all the measurements need to be responsive and change in relation to the screen... note: *all* measurements. Take a look at what elements & measurements in your design have fixed widths and are not getting smaller on small screens... (hint, there are 2)

Comment: @FluffyKitten it's okay, guidance will help me. i think i've solved it by remove the padding and margin. added text-align:center to the paragraph style. I'm getting there!

Comment: What about the image? Are you keeping that full size of does it need to resize too? :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten, yes it's perfect on my site. just struggling with adding padding between the image and the text now.. not sure if it's display inline block or something else..

Comment: What are you trying to add the padding to, and what id the problem you're having?

Comment: @FluffyKitten i just solved it! phew. i used column widths. and thank you so much for helping me out too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change your source like this:

```html
<div class="post-thumb" style="float:left;" ><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551717743-49959800b1f6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0MjB9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" /></div>
<div class="post-content" style="margin-left:210px;" >
    <h3 class="post-title" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:200%;padding-left:40%;text-align:center;" >Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <p style="padding-left:40%">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
        .post-content {
            margin: inherit !important;
        }
        .post-title {
            padding: inherit !important;
        }
        p {
            padding: inherit !important;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Also, don't forget to add this line into your head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Please note that this is a homework question and the guidelines are to lead the OP to the answer, and not do that work for them. Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: appreciate the response! however i have made it work on my own (felt like an sense of relief), just currently working on padding now.